# Storing list in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, storing-data

I am working on function in python 3.8 to store my list of Ideas inside ideas.txt file and after getting new entry updating list in file. For some reason it works only for first entry and then becomes messy ie:
[(1, '["[\'aaa\']", \'sss\']'), (2, 'ddd')]

here is my code:

```
def add_idea():
while True:
    with open("ideas.txt","r") as f:
        updated_list = f.readlines()
        idea=input("What is your new idea?"+"\n")
        idea=str(idea)
        updated_list.append(idea)
        "\n".join(updated_list)
        f.close()
    with open("ideas.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(str(updated_list))
        f.close()
        num_list = list(enumerate(updated_list,1))
        print(num_list)
```

I'm new to python and programming so please be kind ;)

Comment: `f.write(str(updated_list))` is not a reasonable way to serialize a list object. Don't do it. use a pre-defined serialization format, like `json` or `pickle`

Comment: btw, what, exactly, were you not expecting about: `[(1, '["[\'aaa\']", \'sss\']'), (2, 'ddd')]`?

Comment: You don't need to call `f.close()`. That's what `with...` blocks are for.

Comment: The statement `"\n".join(updated_list)` does *absolutely nothing* - you produced a string from the list, but didn't store it or otherwise do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def add_idea():
    while (idea := input("What is your new idea?"+"\n")):
        with open("ideas.txt","a") as f:
            print(idea, file=f)
```

Some notes:

- use the Walrus operator
- you do not need to close the file explicitly because it will be closed once you go out of scope
- you should have a way to exit out of the while/input loop